# Sitecore Hackathon 2017

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

The 2017 Sitecore Hackathon is a free online community driven event organized by Akshay Sura and supported by Sitecore. (Shout out to Pieter and Mark).

Build and submit a Sitecore module best implementing the idea for the Hackathon, as determined by our panel of judges. The idea(s) will be announced an hour before the Hackathon starts on March 3rd.

Teams that have signed up by 6 pm EST (22:00 UTC) February 17, 2017 will have the opportunity to participate in the contest. Eligible teams will have 24 hours —

starting Friday March 3rd 2017 at 8PM EST (00:00 UTC March 4th) and ending Saturday March 4th 2017 at 8PM EST (00:00 UTC March 5th)

Click here for more information: https://goo.gl/MeY7l0

Comment: Event added to community board. Display timer set to 60 days.

Comment: The disposition and accommodation for these types of posts/activities is currently under consideration and will be resolved in the upcoming weeks.

Comment: This has now been resolved.